# Can you get a single value in a 'distinct' array with pymongo?

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to get a single result in an array given by distinct, so that it doesn't include [] around it.

```
channel = db.settings.distinct("main_channel", {"guild": member.guild.name})
print(channel)
```

The output needed is `'output'` or preferably `output`, but I'm getting `['output', 'output2', 'etc']`.

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @JohnnyHK I'm trying to output the value of 'main_channel' from the guild that the user ran the code in. There is multiple documents for that guild, and I need just one.

Comment: But there are multiple values as indicated in your attempt with using `distinct`. How do you know which one to use?

Comment: @JohnnyHK The oldest document would work.